# Trying to extract json value from one to many columns on bigquery

Tags: json, google-bigquery, text-extraction

I am trying to model a table where one of the columns contains:

```
[{"code": "SEEYOUSOON100", "amount": "250.00", "type": "percentage"}]
```

Any solution from [[bigquery documentation]](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract) website returns as null.

Answer (score 3):

Consider below approach

```
select 
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.code') as code,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.amount') as amount,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.type') as type
from your_table, 
unnest(json_extract_array(col)) json
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

You can play/test with above using below cte

```
with your_table as (
  select '[{"code": "SEEYOUSOON100", "amount": "250.00", "type": "percentage"}]' col
)
select 
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.code') as code,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.amount') as amount,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.type') as type
from your_table, 
unnest(json_extract_array(col)) json
```